# already defines member called X c# model

Tags: c#

Have class Books and there i should implement two foreign tables. Comments and Rating. This is the class:

```
 public class Books
    {

        public Books()
        {
            CommentsList = new List<Comments>();
        }

        public Books()
        {
            RatingList = new List<Rating>();
        }

        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }

        public virtual string Category { get; set; }

        public virtual string ISBN { get; set; }

        public virtual string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual string Image { get; set; }

      //  public virtual int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public virtual Categories Categories { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Comments> CommentsList { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Rating> RatingList { get; set; }

        public virtual void AddComment(Comments comm)
        {
            comm.Books = this;
            CommentsList.Add(comm);
        }

        public virtual void AddRating(Rating rating)
        {
            rating.Books = this;
            RatingList.Add(rating);
        }


    }
```

It gives an error

> Error 2   already defines a member called 'Books' with the same
>   parameter types

How to solve this to have possibility to add comments and rating to a book ?

Comment: because you have two constructors which are exactly the same!

Comment: if you need two forgin key why don't you put them in one constructor

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are all of your properties `virtual`? If you are using Entity Framework then only the navigational properties need to be `virtual` (`public virtual Categories Categories { get; set; }`, `public virtual ICollection<Comments> CommentsList { get; set; }`, etc).

Comment: Using Fluent NHibernate mapping. Readed that everything should be virtual.

Comment: @dongou Oh okay, that makes sense then.

Answer (score 4):

You have the same constructor two times. I guess you're using Entity Framework and if I recall correctly, you want to change those `IList`s to `ICollection`s to use the Entity Framework lazy-loading features.

Change

```
public class Books
{

    public Books()
    {
        CommentsList = new List<Comments>();
    }

    public Books()
    {
        RatingList = new List<Rating>();
    }
}
```

To :

```
public class Books
{
    public Books()
    {
        CommentsList = new List<Comments>();
        RatingList = new List<Rating>();
    }
}
```

Comment: So whole code would be : 

`public class Books
{
    public Books()
    {
        CommentsList = new List<Comments>();
        RatingList = new List<Rating>();
    }
}`

`Then, for adding comments would be :

public virtual void AddComment(Comments comm)
        {
            comm.Books = this;
            CommentsList.Add(comm);
        }`


And for rating :

 `public virtual void AddRating(Rating rating)
        {
            rating.Books = this;
            RatingList.Add(rating);
        }`

So when have to add rating, use AddRating and so on ?

Comment: I don't know NHibernate but yes, I think that's correct. Did you get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't have two constructors that have the same signature.  You should consider using [a builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) instead.

You would typically hide the constructors (make them private) and instead expose static methods like `CreateFromComments` and `CreateFromRatings`.

```
private Books() { }

public static Books CreateFromComments()
{
    var ret = new Books();
    ret.CommentsList = new List<Comments>();
    return ret;
}

public static Books CreateFromRatings()
{
    var ret = new Books();
    ret.RatingsList = new List<Ratings>();
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Some help ?? Example ?

Comment: While this is a very useful design pattern, I don't think it's the right fit for @dongou.

Comment: @JimmyBoh -- ...because...?

Comment: @roryap Because this isn't a question about having two similar "constructors" with different purposes, it's a question about why the provided syntax is invalid. (that and it doesn't make any sense as to why you'd make two different builder methods that each initialize a different list)

Answer (score 0):

may be you can pass a boolean param to set the list to initialize...

```
    public Books(bool comments)
    {
        if (comments)
            CommentsList = new List<Comments>();
        else
            RatingList = new List<Rating>();
    }
```